# Enumerating Domain Controllers using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory throws exception

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have written the following code to get a map of all Domains and DCs in the forest. But when I try to enumerate the `currDomain.DomainControllers` some of the Domains throws exception:

> "Unable to obtain DNS hostname of Active Directory domain controller
>   with ntdsa object name"

But, if use other tools like dsquery I able to get all DCs. Can some one please explain why?

```
try
{
    foreach (Domain currDomain in Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains)
    {
        try
        {
            DomainControllerCollection DCs = currDomain.DomainControllers;
            if (DCs.Count > 0)
            {
                //This map is declared already
                dictionaryDomainTree[currDomain.Name] = new List<string>();
                foreach (DomainController controller in DCs)
                {                       
                    dictionaryDomainTree[currDomain.Name].Add(controller.Name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not find Domain Controllers in Domain " + currDomain.Name);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not read the Domains in the Forest");
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Were any of the DC's demoted recently? Has any domain been removed from the forest? If so, there might be a problem with the cleanup. Though title is unrelated, but check the resolutions suggested here -> https://support.microsoft.com/kn-in/help/960370/you-receive-an-error-message-when-you-try-to-open-deployment-manager-o

Comment: Thanks, let me check

Comment: The problem is that dnshostname attribute is not set for some reason. You have 2 option: set the attribute manually (located in configuration partition of ad, should set dc fqdn as a value) or write a method, that will query domain controllers manually which is preferred.